# Audiovisualiser not visible

Tags: ffmpeg

The code below runs a perfect red audiovisualizer when run on a “black” colored background. But when used with any other colored jpg image the visualizer just doesn't show up. What's missing?

```
ffmpeg -y -i music.mp3 -loop 1 -i black.jpg -filter_complex \
   "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=Red:mode=p2p,format=yuv420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay=0:200[outv]" \
   -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest output_bg.mp4
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=Red:mode=p2p[v];[1:v][v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto,format=yuv420p[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- Remove the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter after showwaves.
- Use `format=auto` in the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filter.
- Do all of the filtering within the filtergraph, so remove `-pix_fmt` and replace it with the format filter.

If you want `image.jpg` to fit within a specific size such as 1280x720:

```
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=Red:mode=p2p[fg];[1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1280:720,setsar=1[bg];[bg][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto,format=yuv420p[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: tested your script but the issue still persists.On closer inspection ,the visualizer is there ,it is just getting pushed to the bottom of the page(Some spikes in the frequency could be seen at the page bottom ).How could the visualizer  be bought to the center?.

Comment: @starzar Updated answer. It will now center the overlay. The second example will resize images to fit within 1280x720 without needing to pre-process with ImageMagick.

Comment: thanks for script .There is a padding (default black) under the visualiser (in the original script ),how could one change the color of this padding ?I tried adding option  "overlay :colors= Blue" but received an error= "Option 'colors' not found"

Comment: @starzar Show a screenshot so I can see what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Scale does matter while creating ffmpeg videos with images.

In the above case, some background images were really small (eg 512 x 210 etc).
On doing a batch size conversion  of all the background images (using Imagemagick)to 1280x720 (same as render size) the above code works fine